# Misplaced popover using angular template with ng-bootstrap popover

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, templates, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm working in a project where we are using Angular with ng-bootstrap and various other plugins and it's Great.

But when using ng-repeat inside a ng-template for some popover content, the placement of the popover gets wonky.

```
<script id="broken.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <div>
      <table class="table table-condensed table-popover">
          <tbody ng-repeat="a in test">
          <tr>
              <th>test</th>
              <td>aaa</td>
          </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>
  </div>
</script>
```

[Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/FGMTnb4rWe9p8byr5Yy4?p=preview).

The "Broken" button that uses ng-repeat spwans a popup that is too far down. While the "Works" button that has the table hard coded works as intended.

Does anyone have an idea of how one might fix this problem?

Best regards, Fredrik

Comment: See if it works when you add your ng-repeat in the <tr> tag. I assume you do not want to create a new tbody everytime.

Comment: Please note it is only broken the first time the popover appears. Further click are not concerned by the issue

Comment: You are using a customized version of angular-ui-bootstrap as there is no popover-template directive.  The problem is most likely in the tooltip provider show or create method not calling a $digest but I would need to see the unminified version to help further.